# How to get content on a blank basket/cart page in a custom theme with woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I'm working on an e-commerce site with a custom theme and I have been trying to integrate it with woocommerece, the shop and product page display just fine and work the way they should but when I go to the basket/cart page, it's blank the HTML is exactly this

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Things I've checked/done so far

- Basket page is present (generated by woocommerce).
- Basket page has [woocommerce_cart] short code.
- Woocommerce is configured to use this page.
- I changed my theme to twentytwenty and the basket page shows up just fine but if I revert to my theme, the blank page situation reappears
- If I add page-basket.php to my theme and add some content to it like a header with hello in it, it shows up just fine
- Tried deleting the basket page and regenerating it but no dice.
- Turned on debug logs but nothing is there.
- Removed the woocommerce folder under my theme and reload page but still nothing.

I don't know if this is relevant but I copied **all** of the contents of the templates folder under the woocommerce plugin into MYTHEME/woocommerce. I also copied the same folder into the twentytwenty theme but it still works.

I'm on woocommerce 4.0.1

I have no idea what this could be and I'm stumped, any suggestions would be welcome

EDIT: I've also looked at the twentytwenty source and I cannot see how they are implementing woocommerce support, there's no reference to woocommerce at all.

EDIT: I also have woocommerce support in my theme

```
function add_woocommerce_support()
{
   add_theme_support('woocommerce');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support');
```

Comment: did you add add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); in after_setup_theme action hook in your theme's functions.php file ?

Comment: Yes I have, I'll add that to the question, I've also discovered that basket is not the only page that is affected by this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reintroducing my page-basket.php to my project and adding the line below to it and everything worked out just fone.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_cart]"); ?>
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do things but it works